# Confluent.Kafka SchemaRegistry: reusing Avro schemas?

Tags: schema, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Avro supports schema reusing. One might put one custom type in file `a.avsc` and reuse it in the another file `b.avsc`. That's fatefully important for more or less complicated projects to avoid having identical entities under different namespaces and overflood with stupid mappings between them and protect. But I see no such possibility mentioned in the official documentantion of the Confluent Kafka platform. Does it mean that there is no way to reuse schemas?